# Find used packages inside a folder in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am aware of the `npm ls --depth=0` to find all installed packages but is there a way to find all used packages/imports for 3rd party libs inside a specific folder?

Comment: Normally all packages would be inside the `package.json` at top level, trying to find which packages are used inside a folder seems more like something you should do by searching in your IDE, rather than an npm feature.

Comment: Doesn't really make sense to do that with IDE (unless VSCode has a feature for this) to find all import statements manually as can be hundreds if not thousands of files to go through.